# Function scope unit test with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am pretty new with Angular and unit test but I need to do some for my app. What I need is just some guidance on how to do it.

Below is my code that I need to test

```
var app = angular.module('quizApp', []);

app.directive('quiz', function(quizFactory) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.start = function() {
                scope.id = 0;
                scope.quizOver = false;
                scope.inProgress = true;
                scope.getQuestion();
            };

            scope.reset = function() {
                scope.inProgress = false;
                scope.score = 0;
            }
```

And this is what I've been testing so far.

```
describe('$scope.start', function() {
        it('Should start the quiz as long as start button is pressed', function() {
            $scope.id = 0;
            $scope.quizOver = false;
            $scope.inProgress = true;

            expect(0).toBe(0);
            expect(false).not.toBe(true);
            expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

My tests don't work as I am getting errors. Does anyone can tell me how to do it right? Many thanks

Comment: The describe code block, is that everything in that file? There should be more setup prior to testing your directive.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/wFFet/